Unable to install Python package llama-index-embeddings-huggingface
I am trying to implement the code discussed in the HuggingFace cookbook article at https://huggingface.co/learn/cookbook/en/rag_llamaindex_librarian.
I get to the point where I am trying to install the package in question:
llama-index-embeddings-huggingface

I get the following error:
ERROR: Cannot install llama-index-embeddings-huggingface==0.1.3, llama-index-embeddings-huggingface==0.1.4 and llama-index-embeddings-huggingface==0.1.5 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
llama-index-embeddings-huggingface 0.1.5 depends on torch<3.0.0 and >=2.1.2
llama-index-embeddings-huggingface 0.1.4 depends on torch<3.0.0 and >=2.1.2
llama-index-embeddings-huggingface 0.1.3 depends on torch<3.0.0 and >=2.1.2

I assume that torch is PyTorch, which is not currently installed.
I am using the command:
python3 -m pip install llama-index-embeddings-huggingface

which causes the mentioned error.
I am not sure what to try to resolve the conflict.

Which version of python are you using? I had the same issue while attempting to install llama-index-embeddings-huggingface on python 3.13.0. I downgraded to python 3.12.8 and it worked.
If you aren't committed to a specific version of python, try it again on 3.12.8. You can use pyenv: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv to manage multiple python installations on your machine.
